# How to use active and before with CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I would create an effect with CSS using pseudo-class `::before` `:active`.
I created an effect that if you click the element of p before, content before p changes.
I thought that didn't work because before p can't be select.
This is my code, but doesn't work:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > p::before {
  content: 'ON';
}

p:active + p:before {
  content: 'OFF';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"><p></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas — Not true. You can click on any element. Interactive or not. (It's bad practise to design a site that way, but not a barrier to mouse users).

Comment: Also...[**paragraphs are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/). If you want a button...use a `button`.

Comment: Note. :active is a pseudo-class but ::before creates a pseudo-element. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p:active + p:before` means *The pseudo-element that appears before the paragraph which is **immediately after** the (other) paragraph which the mouse is pointing to while the mouse button is pressed*.

Since you only have one paragraph, that can't ever match anything.

Perhaps you meant `p:active:before`?

```css
.container {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > p::before {
  content: 'ON';
}

p:active:before {
  content: 'OFF';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"><p></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change this rule, `p:active + p:before`, to `p:active:before`

```css
.container {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > p::before {
  content: 'ON';
}

p:active:before {
  content: 'OFF';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"><p></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```